# How do I handle the failure of a command in a bash function?

Tags: bash

I have a bash function on one of our test servers that deploys our code, but one of the commands fails frequently and we can't find the cause. We just retry until it works.

I want to have the function retry if that command fails. In the function, I did something like this:

```
command_to_run || { echo "failed, retrying"; call_function; }
```

Which calls the function again like I would want, but it also allows the function to continue execution. How do I stop the execution of the current function before calling it again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an even simpler variant of @terdon's suggestion:

```
while ! command_to_run; do
    echo "failed, retrying"
    sleep 1
done
```

`while` actually takes a command, so it can test the success/failure of `command_to_run` directly rather than having to deal with `$?`. Normally, `while` runs the loop as long as the command succeeds; in this case, I use `!` to negate that and run the loop as long as the command fails (i.e. until it succeeds).

Comment: +1 This is the better answer.

Comment: Indeed it is, +1.

Answer (score 4):

Try a while loop:

```
er=1; while [[ $er != 0 ]]; do command_to_run; er=$?; sleep 1; done
```

Bash saves the exit status of the last command in the special variable `$?`. The loop above saves the exit status of `command_to_run` as `$er` and then reruns the command until an exit status of `0` (exited correctly) is returned. It will wait one second between runs as suggested by [Flup](https://superuser.com/users/203009/flup) in the comments below.

Comment: might want to put a `sleep` in there to avoid a tight loop.

Comment: @Flup good point, done.

Comment: The sleep won't be necessary as the command is a long running one. This worked like a charm though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find `until` is more readable in this case.

```
until command_to_run; do
    echo "failed, retrying"
    sleep 1
done
```